# In geometry nodes, Object Info doesn't follow the image texture, but primitive cube does

Tags: geometry-nodes

I used an image texture on my geometry nodes. If I use the cube node, it follows the UVMap properly:

[image: target reference]

But if I use a cube I created without anything, just a newly created cube, it doesn't follow the texture mapping. How do I fix this? I tried to generate different types of UVMaps for the external Cube object but nothing worked.

[image: using external cube]

I am guessing it has something to do with the texture mapping, but I can't find any information or clue to fix it.

There is nothing much to it, I just made a simple scene to illustrate my problem. I just used a square image logo on a 100x100 grid and ran Instance on points. Just the standard Image Texture inside geometry nodes setup, very easy to replicate. My only concern is how to use an external object imported via the Object Info node instead of the primitive mesh Cube node.

[image: additional info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the failing case, the geometry is picking up the externally created UV map of the *cube*, and maps the image to each one.

There's a 'convenient' default getting in your way. It seems that if both the cube's and the grid's UV maps have the *same name*, whatever that name is, then the cube's UV map is given priority.

If you delete the cube's UV map, then  the grid's UV map is picked up.

If you rename either of the maps, then you can aim the input attribute at the right one.

Even if the cube's UV-map-name is not listed in the grid GN modifier's input attribute dropdown, you can type it in, and it will be picked up, mapping the image to the *cubes*' vertices, interpolating the image between them, like vertex colors.

If the cube is created in the GN tree, it has no map other than the one on the GN-modified object, so, no problem.

**TL;DR**

It's a good idea to give your UV maps unique names, so you always know which one the GN modifier is referring to.

Comment: Thanks, Robin, that's a very detailed and very informative answer. Indeed, it solved my problem instantly as soon as I deleted the UVMap of the cube. I couldn't thank you enough.

Comment: @Sophia np! playing through the variations taught me stuff, too.